# Error While using Material UI within React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I was following a youtube tutorial about building an app in React JS.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngc9gnGgUdA

In that tutorial I created an App as described in it [time stamp: https://youtu.be/ngc9gnGgUdA?t=1993].

```
import React from 'react';
import {Container, AppBar, Typography, Grid, Grow} from '@material-ui/core';
import memories from './images/memories.png'



const App = ()=>{
    return (
        <Container maxidth='lg'>
            <AppBar position='static' color="inherit">
                <Typography variant='h2' align="center">Memories</Typography>
                <img src={memories} alt='memories' height='60' />
            </AppBar>
        </Container>
        
    );
}
export default App;
```

But I am getting this error,

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

I am beginner I may not have covered everything regarding problem statement, please ask if you require further information regarding my problem.

Comment: Can you provide the callstack/stacktrace for the error, or what component it is occurring in? I don't see any hooks being used in the snippet you provided. What version of React are you using?

Comment: please add code sample in codesandbox for debugging is better

Comment: Here is complete error log
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y7xpoXPCrzjBhVRvCIaLismL2OSEOorm/view?usp=sharing

And react version is 17.0.1

Comment: Is this the only file you have inside the project except `index.js` ?

Comment: Please include all code, error messages, etc... in your question. Links tend to decay over time.

Comment: @Dilshan yes its the only App I am including in my index.js

Comment: Hi, thanx everyone for your time. The problem is solved. It was a problem with my file structure. I divided the project in two apps, [client side and server side]. I installed Material UI in my main project folder, actually it was supposed to be installed in Client folder, where Material UI components were being used. 

Sorry for taking your time for such a beginner mistake.